# Rendering Backbone (or Angular, Ember) template inside a Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js

Is it possible to render a Backbone template as a Rails partial? Most of my site uses simple ERB views, but some of the frontend of my site is more complex and it might make more sense to use a JS framework. I'm able to render one inside of the Rails application layout, but I need some more flexibility than that allows. I'd like to be able to click a button, and have the template appear (slide out) within a Rails view.  I don't want to have to load another page every time a user decides to use something like a chat box (similar to Facebook). I'm open to using any JS frameworks that allow me to do this. I've started with Backbone, but I'm willing to learn anything.

Is this possible, or would my entire front-end have to be built in JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a lot of flexibility by extending your backbone views with a composite view utility class that allows you to create subviews within your views; I prefer jst.ejs templates.

Basically have a static pages route on the Rails API that initializes the Backbone app. Then pipe out your data in Rails via a JSON api using something like jbuilder. Then you can build your backbone app on top of that with a composite view + subview class and it will offer much more flexibility. I hope this helps!